# How to convert this custom IP into Vivado IP integrator component?

Tags: xilinx, vivado

Here is my custom IP component. It has an AXI4 slave bus on one end and a simpler custom bus on the other end. It serves as a bridge function between the two. I am trying to find a way to package this RTL module so Vivado understands that it has an AXI4 and a custom bus on it so I don't have to manually connect every single connection on this component.

[image]

Intel Quartus Platform Designer provides a very neat way to create IP for use in their systems. Microsemi Libero SoC SmartDesign also has a neat way to do it. However, I am not able to track down how to do this simple task in Xilinx Vivado.

I briefly attempted the "Create and Package New IP..." and "Create Interface Definition..." but they are not intuitive and give impression that they are not designed for what I am trying to achieve.

What resource can I use to solve this problem? There are a few more modules like this that have AXI4 or some other bus along with discrete signals. I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Create and Package New IP" is definitely overkill if you just want tidy grouping of intetface signals in the block design diagram.

"Create Interface Definition" is for when you want to define a new custom interface, but as you can imagine the various AXI variants are already defined in vivado.

If you want vivado to group your signals properly you have two options
[as explained here](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug994-vivado-ip-subsystems/Inferring-Control-Signals-in-a-RTL-Module):

- Use default naming for signals, so for a slave interface `s_axi_<signame>` and for a master `m_axi_<signame>`
- Use the (xilinx-specific) `X_INTERFACE_INFO` attribute in your source. For example for your `i_s_axi_awaddr` signal:

  ```
   ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO : STRING;
   ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO of i_s_axi_awaddr: SIGNAL is "xilinx.com:interface:aximm:1.0 i_s_axi_awaddr AWADDR";
  ```

The second solution is very tedious and also adds quite some clutter to your sources, so I would suggest sticking to the first option.

Comment: So by clutter you mean all those VHDL attribute lines?

Comment: Yes, but it's just a personal preference

Comment: Your point about the "xilinx.com:interface:aximm:1.0" is actually quite helpful. However, what if I have created a custom interface and put it into my repository. Is it possible to use the VHDL attributes for that too?

Comment: Never tried with a custom interface, but if it is defined in the project I don't see why it shouldn't.